# Java NullPointerException null when calling forge.ajax

Tags: trigger.io

When calling `forge.ajax` and request returns a 401 with JSON, under Android only (both device and emulator) I'm getting the following error message:

```
[   INFO] D/Forge   (25373): Returning: {"content":{"type":"UNEXPECTED_FAILURE","message":"Forge Java error: NullPointerException: null","full_error":"java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat io.trigger.forge.android.modules.request.API$1$1.getPasswordAuthentication(API.java:107)\n\tat java.net.Authenticator.requestPasswordAuthentication(Authenticator.java:140)\n\tat libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getAuthorizationCredentials(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:432)\n\tat libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processAuthHeader(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)\n\tat libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:356)\n\tat libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)\n\tat libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)\n\tat io.trigger.forge.android.modules.request.API$1.run(API.java:285)\n\tat io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeTask$1.doInBackground(ForgeTask.java:112)\n\tat android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)\n\tat android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)\n"},"status":"error","callid":"46C2A570-7229-4427-9BF8-F64FB12F6D8F"}
```

The forge.ajax error callback is being fired but the error.content object contains the string above and does not have the response.
Notice that this is not happening on iOS.

You can see this in action when running the app from the [play store](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boorgle.app) and trying to login with a wrong password/non existing user.

Full source code is available on [github](http://github.com/burgalon/boorgle-spine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This arose when attempting to access HTTP resources protected with basic auth, and no username was supplied to request.ajax.

The bug was fixed in v1.4.24 of the platform - sorry for the inconvenience!

http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-24